# How to use VrVideoView in Reverse Landscape?

Tags: android, landscape, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, vrvideoview

My `Activity` is in Reverse Landscape but when a start the `VrVideoView` the screen rotate in Landscape. Do have a idea to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

What phone is this? And does it rotate to the wrong orientation in embedded mode or when full screened?